# 3 inputs to a binary calculator logic gate circuit. The first two bits are reserved for 1 operand, the last bit is the second operand.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

The question was:
Create the necessary Boolean equations based on the
scenario below. Simplify the equations depending on the
output if necessary.
There are 3 inputs to a binary calculator logic gate circuit. The
first two bits are reserved for 1 operand, the last bit is the
second operand. There would be only three output bits that
will communicate the result to communicate it later in
decimal. Create a logic gate circuit that will support all sums of every input.

This is how we got the truth table using this table.

| in3 | in2 | in1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| out3 | out2 | out1 |
| 2² | 2¹ | 2⁰ |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

We have arrived at the this truth table:

| in1 | in2 | in3 | out3 | out2 | out1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I'm lost on how we arrived at the resulting truth table above using the table before the truth table.

Comment: Hmm, I think the first table simply shows how the 3 bits are used to encode a number. For example, if the output is supposed to be the number $6$, you encode this in binary with $110$ ... in particular you's set $out0$ to $0$, and $out1$ and $out2$ to $1$. Input is less clear: which bits are the 'first' two bits? Are they $in0$ and $in1$? But then if the 'last' bit is $in2$, does that mean that the second operand is either the number $0$ or the number $4$?  Most pressingly:  what is the operation supposed to be conceptually/mathematically?  Or do they just *give* you that as the second table?

Comment: @Bram28, I believe the first two bits are in1 and in2 (first operand) and in3(second operand) as the 3rd bit, we would later create the logic gate circuit that will support all sums of every input. So, if we would get to the binary value 1 0 0 in the first row, we would need to do 1 1 + 1.

Comment: Hmm .. but that would mean that $in3$ (contrary as what seems to be indicated in the first table) does not stand for $4$ or $0$, but simply for $1$ or $0$. That is, $in3$ works like $in1$ and $out1$. Anyway, with that interpretation, and knowing that the desired operation is addition, then the second table does make total sense: The rows show, in order: 3+1=4, 3+0=3, 2+1=3, 2+0=2, 1+1=2, 1+0=1, 0+1=1, and 0+0=0. Indeed, once we know the encoding of input and output numbers, and knowing that the operation is addition, then you can generate the second table accordingly.

Comment: Oh, and make sure to add what you just said in the comment to the post. In particular: the the operation is supposed to be addition ... you left us completely in the dark on that one :P